Replaced ceiling fan, had 2 working switches, now only 1
I replaced a ceiling fan that had a burned out motor with a new one, a Hunter Channing. The single wall switch has 2 throws. Previously the top one turned the fan light on and off, and the bottom throw turned fan motor on and off.
Now the bottom throw controls power to the fan and light, and the top throw does nothing. What could I have done wrong?


Can you post photos of the inside of the ceiling fan box please?

Did your new fan come with a remote control?  If so it's very likely that it's not designed to work with two wall switches - even if the box says it is.

No, the fan did not come with a remote or receiver. picture posted of fan wiring

There is nothing obviously wrong with the wiring at the switch. Can you share with us: 1. A photograph of the wiring at the fan; 2. The instructions for connecting the fan in single-switch operation and any other instructions there might be for changing the fan operation between single-switch and dual-switch operation.

This is somewhat simple.  You connected the wires at the fan incorrectly.
From your picture of your switch it looks like you're in North America. The fan wiring should be:
Bare copper (ground) to green or yellow with green stripe.
White (neutral) to white
Black (bottom switched hot in your case)  to black to run the fan.
Red (top switched hot)  to the blue wire to the fan's light.
If your fan has different wiring post a picture but this is common wiring for most fans in the US.

i did connect the wires as you described, using the terminal block that came with the fan

double check the wiring in the fan box.  You may think you have it correct, but something is wrong.
